# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'SpiceShop.Models.Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Products'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I Have Database that contains 2 tables

```
TABLE Categories (CategoriesId, Name, Description)
TABLE Products (ProductId, CategoriesId, Title, ProductImageUrl)
```

Categories is linked to Products by CategoriesId.

I am trying to use LINQ to get all of a particular Title.

```
 public ActionResult Browse(string categories)
 {
     var spices = spiceDB.Products.Include("Products").Single(p => p.Title == categories);                 
     return View(spices);
 }
```

Product Model

```
namespace SpiceShop.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }
        public List <Categorie> Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Categorie Model

```
namespace SpiceShop.Models
{
    public class Categorie
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        //public List<Product> ProductId { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean to query for one entity and include another with a FK relationship? or is this a misunderstanding as Felipe believes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

It looks like your View requires a Model that is a single object of type "Product".

Also, I have tried to give each of my identifiers/variables a name that best conveys their meaning and intent.

---

**Edit 2:**

Please note that changing any input parameter names on a method will require a corresponding change in your View code that calls the method.
In MVC, Action-Method parameters are [automatically mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd410269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Your debug shows a URL of `Browse?categories=Sauces`, which is automatically mapped to the method "Browse" with input parameter `categories` set to "Sauces". But (my version of) the Browse method is expecting a `categoryName` parameter, not `categories`. So you will need to make sure that URL Attribute and the Method Parameter have exactly the same name.

---

So if you really need to pass the selected Category's Name as the input parameter:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string categoryName)
{
    // Gets the CategoryId for the given categoryName, or zero if not found.
    var categoryId = spiceDB.Categories
        .Where(c => c.Name == categoryName)
        .Select(c => c.CategoriesId)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // Gets the first Product (only) for the specified categoryId.
    var firstProduct = category.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CategoriesId == categoryId);

    return View(firstProduct);
}
```

However, a much more common usage scenario for supporting this type of "parent-child" relationship would be:

- Your Category List invokes a query by ID when clicked, not a query by Name (i.e. 3, not "Pickles")
- Your View supports all the related Products, not just the first one (i.e. a model of type `List<Product>`, not just `Product`)

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Browse(int categoryId)
{
    var products = spiceDB.Products
        .Where(p => p.CategoriesId == categoryId) 
        .ToList();

    return View(products);
}
```

i.e. making your Product List more comprehensive, and your data access code simpler and more efficient.

Comment: In case his View is expecting a list of spices, that's the correct solution. I made the (possibly wrong) assumption that he wanted to return only one row, because that's what the view was expecting.

Comment: @FelipeCastro, I still lean toward your understanding b/c use of single. But, to be fair, reading the OP's intentions requires a psychic.

Comment: There are two table
TABLE Categories (CategoriesId, Name, Description)
TABLE Products (ProductId, CategoriesId, Title,ProductImageUrl)

Categories  Table Name
Products Table Title(Product name details) If i add this code say The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[SpiceShop.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SpiceShop.Models.Product'.

Comment: Are you trying to get **all** Products with a particular Title?  Or just **the first** Product with a particular Title?

Comment: I am new for Linq, there are two table
TABLE Categories (CategoriesId, Name, Description) Primary key CategoriesId
TABLE Products (ProductId, CategoriesId, Title,ProductImageUrl) Primary key ProductId, 


For Example: Categories Table Name Field data
Cordials and Syrups
Sauces
Pickles


Products Table Title field (Categories Table name field details)

Comment: So an example Category Name might be "Cordials and Syrups"?  And some example Product Titles might be "Raspberry Cordial" and "Cranberry Cordial"?  And you want to retrieve all Products that have the search term "berry" somewhere in the Title? Or have I got it completely wrong?  :)

Comment: search or click display all items in 
Categories Table name field select one item, display products table Title field relevent details.
For Example: somebody click London, in Categories Table. It'll display details 'London is UK capital city' in Products table Title field

Comment: I hope you'll forgive my confusion, as 'London is UK capital city' is neither a spice nor a sauce  :)  Anyway, I see that each Category may have many Products.  When a Category is selected, do you want to display the Title of each Product for the selected Category?  Or just the Title of the "first" Product in the Category.

Comment: just the Title of the "first" Product in the Category

Comment: There are few issuses.  Please follow this url pdf file http://www.bluesapphires.com.au/test/spices.pdf If you like you can change table design because I am new for Linq.

Comment: f I use this code public ActionResult Browse(int categoryId)
{
    var products = spiceDB.Products
        .Where(p => p.CategoriesId == categoryId) 
        .ToList();

    return View(products);
} it will come The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'categoryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Browse(Int32)' in 'SpiceShop.Controllers.ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters.

Comment: When I use your first code categoryName and firstProduct come null CategoriesId will come 0, please refer debug pdf http://www.bluesapphires.com.au/test/Debug.pdf

Comment: Do you have any idea how do I create MVC contact us form?

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you mark this as the answer, or upvote it? (or both?)  I would be glad to finally get to 1000 points  :)  Your Contact Us form definitely needs to be a separate question  :)

Comment: I am testing your second method
public ActionResult Browse(int categoryId)
{
    var products = spiceDB.Products
        .Where(p => p.CategoriesId == categoryId) 
        .ToList();

    return View(products);
}

When I debug categoryId will come correct but products value will come Count=1 Why was that?  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SpiceShop.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SpiceShop.Models.Product

Comment: Your view may have a statement such as `@model SpiceShop.Models.Product`, but if you want your model to be a `List<Product>` instead, then this statement will need to be `@model List<SpiceShop.Models.Product>`.

Comment: if i add Browse.cshtml @model List<SpiceShop.Models.Product>. How do I display Product table field Title?

Comment: Title for each list member? Probably worthy of a separate question  :)  But basically: `@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    <div>@product.Title</div>
}`

Comment: Your both method are working. Well done. Thank you for help and support. I learned a lot. Best Regards

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the .Include("Products"), that's not how it's used.

The error is clear, there is no "Products" property at your "Product" model.

Comment: Just for clarification, the .Include() method should be used only for optimizing performance in cases where you want the entities to be fetch by using Eager Loading, rather than Lazy Loading.

Comment: Also, you're querying for Product titles using the name of categories, are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: if remove the include it say "Sequence contains no elements"             var spices = spiceDB.Products.Single(p => p.Title == categories);

Comment: That means there isn't any product with the specified title in your db. The .Single() method throws this exception because it assumes there's always one (and only one) matching record. If you don't know for sure that there will be, replace .Single for .First

Comment: That's because the sequence contains no elements. Your expression looks wrong. You probably meant something like .Single(p => p.Categories.Name == category); And since you pass in categories, I assume that's a delimited list which you need to parse first. If I'm wrong, then you should probably rename your variables as they are confusing.

Comment: Also, you're querying for Product titles using the name of categories, are you sure that's what you want to do? – Yes

Comment: @FelipeCastro, maybe you should add a syntax you believe WOULD achieve what the OP wants

Comment: `var spices = spiceDB.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title.Contains(categories));`. I also added the "Contains" rather than "==" just in case there's any white spaces in the row at the db.

Comment: please tell me how do I rewrite this line var spices = spiceDB.Products.Single(p => p.Title == categories);

Comment: @DaveA I can suggest some changes, but I can't say for sure it will "achieve his goals" - if there really isn't a matching row in the db, that's not a matter of changing the code.

Comment: Correction, I didn't see your comment with code. Thats as much as can be expected. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you first part working now. but Browse.cshtml say 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  public ActionResult Browse(string categories)
        {
            
            var spices = spiceDB.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title.Contains(categories));
            
           
            return View(spices);

        }

Browse.cshtml say 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

@model SpiceShop.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browsing Genre: @Model.Title</h2>

Comment: That's because the result of the query now is "null" (instead of an exception). Change your view to handle this case (when the product doesn't exist), showing a message to the user. Something like `@if(Model == null) { <h2>Product not found</h2> } else { <h2> @Model.Title </h2> } `

Comment: Thanks, if I wrote this code input parameter as "categories" to
public ActionResult Browse(string categories)
        {
            

            var spices = spiceDB.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title.Contains(categories));
            
            
           
            return View(spices);

        }

Comment: If add your code still Products table data is not reading. Model always come null Why was that? var spices = spiceDB.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title.Contains(categories));
            return View(spices);

Comment: Probably because there isn't any product (in the db) whose title contains the term you're looking for (categories).

Comment: DB both two table are data. Please check database details and data pdf file. http://www.bluesapphires.com.au/shop/Db.pdf

Comment: When debugging, check if the parameter "string categories" is valid or null. Also, there seems to be a special character at the beginning of the title of every product, you might want to remove that.